# Any way to set a value dependent breakpoint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xna

I want to know, is there any way in Visual Studio 2008 to set a value breakpoint kind of a thing ? Like say there's a variable called 'test', and I want to the code to stop at any line in the entire project where the value of this variable is being changed .. ?

That is, I don't want any line specific breakpoint .. I just want Visual Studio to stop at the line of code where a change is being made to some variable ..

The code I have is very complex and it would be a lot easier for me to debug the code if I can get the mentioned functionality somehow ..

Comment: Is the variable a member of a class? Could you replace it with a property?

Comment: Yes the variable is a member of a class, but since the code is multithreaded and changes are happing quickly, its difficult for me to know the changes in a sequential manner, and would just like to be notified whenever there's an attempt made to change the value of this variable .. This way I can track how and where the changes are coming from ..

Comment: maybe i misunderstood your question. You can't hit a breakpoint "whenever a variable changes". Your better of using logging here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encapsulate the variable in a property so the field named `test` becomes `_test` or `mTest` or whatever and you create a new property called test that other code will use. You can put the breakpoint on the setter of the property.

So instead of having

```
public int test;
```

You can have

```
private int _test;

public int test
{
  get { return _test; }
  set { _test = value; } // Breakpoint goes here.
}
```

And there's no need to alter any of the users of `test`, unless they've already been compiled in which case you'll need to compile them again.

Comment: No worries. It's a good idea to keep fields private and, if you need to expose them, only do it with properties. Properties can be members of interfaces and if you need to change the implementation to, for example, fire an event when the property changes it's easy with a property. Also, if someone is using a pre-compiled copy of your code changing from a field to a property later is not simple as it requires everything to be compiled again.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, use a **Conditional Breakpoint.**

Set a breakpoint to the line of code you want to debug.

Then right click on the red circle (breakpoint), click "Condition".

Then set the condition that you want to be true in order to breakpoint. (e.g break when "test" == 1).

Keep in mind - you still have to set the breakpoint somewhere, as it needs to have scope of the variable used in the condition.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You use a conditional breakpoint, and in the values, type in the variable name, and change the checkbox from "Is true" to "Has changed".

To set this up, left click on the left hand column where breakpoints appear. A breakpoint will be created.

You then right click on the red glyph that appeared, and select condition from the drop down menu.

This should get you where you need to be.